# OpenMP Parallel and optimisation

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have this code and it is parallelizing efficiently now and provides better results, I just want to know if anyone has any idea if there could be any further optimization done on it! Thanks

This is my code:

```
`/// main loop
iter = 0;
difmax = 1000000.0;

timer_on = omp_get_wtime();
while (difmax > tol) {
    iter++;
    difmax = 0.0;
            // update temperature for next iteration
#pragma omp parallel default(shared) private(i,j,diff)
{

    #pragma omp for schedule(static) collapse(2)
    for (i=1; i <= m; i++) {
        for (j=1; j <= n; j++) {
            tnew[i][j] = (t[i-1][j]+t[i+1][j]+t[i][j-1]+t[i][j+1])/4.0;
            // work out maximum difference between old and new temperatures
            diff = fabs(tnew[i][j]-t[i][j]);
            if (diff > difmax) {
                difmax = diff;
            }
            t[i][j]=tnew[i][j];
        }
    }
}
}
timer_off = omp_get_wtime();`
```

Comment: 1. The `critical` pragma can go. It serves no purpose, and it only slows you down. 2. you need to mark your loop as `reduction(max:diffmax)`. 3. I don't see where you define `diff`, but it should be defined local to the `j` loop. 4. How do you set `nthreads`? I would set the number of threads with the `OMP_NUM_THREAD` environment variable, and remove the `omp_set_num_threads` call. 5. Why did you mark this as an "mpi" question? 6. Yes, what *was* your question?

Comment: there is a typo in your code (`#pragma omp parllel ...`). I strongly encourage you to use `default(none)` to avoid assuming things will work as you expect. Though `iter` is not used in the OpenMP section, you are using it wrong (e.g. race condition). At first glance, I do not think you can `t[i][j] = tnew[i][j]` in the same loop ...

Comment: Beside data race, the real problem is that the result depends on the order of execution: to calculate `tnew[i][j]`, which is subsequently copied to `t[i][j]` you use not only `t[i][j]`, but `t[i-1][j], t[i+1][j], t[i][j-1], t[i][j+1]`. On the other hand, the workload is very small and your code is memory bound. In my opinion to take care of the dependency in such a low workload will result in large overheads, so your code most probably will not gain anything by parallelization.

Comment: yes it is memory bound but i would not jump to any conclusion yet. For example, try flip-flopping with two (pointers to) arrays so you do not need to `t = tnew` and see how/if this improves performance/scalability.

Comment: @Victor
The question is why doesn't it work when I put the line:
#Pragma omp parallel default(shared){
But when I remove it threads work fine.
I marked it as mpi because I ran out of hashtags :D
Thank you man!!

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet
The code still doesn't work with the #pragma parallel shared(none) {
I fixed the typo and still its not using the threads, only one thread is used, I really can not understand why do you have any information?

Comment: Update, Its working now .. but the parallelization is still useless as it takes more time with more threads.

Comment: You say you've updated it, but the code above still shows the `parllel` typo. So we can't answer your question since we have no idea what your code actually is.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Sorry for that, I'm still new here as well, I have updated everything in the question. If you have any optimization advice please let me know. It works well now but its not harmful to get better results without reaching an aggressive optimization point, or should I just go with what I have? Thanks

Comment: are you sure your serial code is even correct? `tnew[1][2]` depends on `t[1][1]` that was updated at the previous iteration so that is either fishy, or means lots of data dependency that make parallelization hard to get correct - not to mention the performance aspect.